# number read and output

Tags: python, numbers

Ok I'm having a little trouble I can get the program to read all the integers but now I'm confused how to get the program to read that is odd or even then add only odd and only even, giving totals for both

```
 def main():
      myfile = open('numbers.txt','r')
      for line in myfile:
          print(line)
      myfile.close()
      myfile=open('numbers.txt','r')
      num1=int(myfile.readline())
      num2=int(myfile.readline())
      num3=int(myfile.readline())
      num4=int(myfile.readline())
      num5=int(myfile.readline())
      num6=int(myfile.readline())
      num7=int(myfile.readline())
      num8=int(myfile.readline())
      num9=int(myfile.readline())
      num10=int(myfile.readline())
      num11=int(myfile.readline())
      num12=int(myfile.readline())
      myfile.close()

      total=num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9+num10+num11+num12
      print('The numbers are:',num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,num10,num11,num12)
      print('Their total is:',total)

  main()
```

Comment: Rather than storing the numbers into their respective variables, you could add them into a `list`. Once the list is populated with all the values you could easily `print` out the numbers and use `sum` on the `list` for even and odd numbers to produce their totals.

Comment: There's a name for this kind of programming: [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions).

Comment: When you start copying code - it's time to refactor!

Answer (score 0):

```
def isEven(number):
    return number % 2 == 0

def main():
    myfile = open('numbers.txt','r')
    nums = []
    for line in myfile:
      num.append(line)
    print('The numbers are '+ str(nums))
    print('Their total is :'+str(sum(nums))))
```

I've reduced your code to DRY standards, and added isEven function
You can call isEven on an integer to determine if it's even or odd.

```
isEven(1) # False
isEven(2) # True
```

Comment: May as well define isEven to be `return int(number) % 2 == 0` and fail with a ValueError since it's only defined over integers anyway. Also, you can avoid the explicit string cast (FWIW) in your last line by passing it to print instead of concatenating it yourself, assuming you're using print-as-a-function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a taste of what are some of all possible solutions to this

```
myfile = open("test.txt")

list_of_num = list()
#same as list_of_num = []

for line in myfile:
    list_of_num.append(int(line)) #this conversion to int() is important
                         #otherwise the "numbers" you read are actually 
                         #strings!
total_sum = 0
for number in list_of_num:
    total_sum = total_sum + number

#or you can also do just
#total_sum = sum(list_of_num)

print("The numbers are: ", end=": ")
for number in list_of_num:
    print(number, end=" ")

print("Their total is: ", total_sum)
```

In the print statements `end` declares what will be at the end of printed string. By default that is new line, however for more compact print look, you can ask it to just leave a single space at the end instead.

Aditionally, for a number to be even, it has to be divisible by 2 without "change" (extra, don't know the right word). You can check if that's true by using modulo operator `%` which returns the remain of the division.

If that remain is 0. Your number is even.

Comment: total_sum can be `sum(list_of_num)`

Comment: @taesu as it was stated in the commented section of the code from the start. Edits were pertaining to explaining how to determine if a number was even. Going brackets berserk on a beginner is confusing.

Comment: Why are you using `float`? When we talk about numbers being even or odd, we are clearly talking about integers.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Same reason I had to edit my answer to add the part about even non-even :D I was focused on his code more than on his question. Answer is corrected now, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant:

```
def main():
    with open('numbers.txt') as my_file:
        numbers = [int(line) for line in my_file]

    print('The numbers are:', *numbers)
    print('Their total is:', sum(numbers))
    print('The total of just the odd ones is:',
          sum(n for n in numbers if n % 2 != 0))
    print('The total of just the even ones is:',
          sum(n for n in numbers if n % 2 == 0))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Things to note:

1. Lists are your friend. The `var1, var2, var3, ..., varN` anti-pattern is never correct.
2. You forgot `if __name__ == '__main__'` which is the whole point of defining a main function like you've got. That's where you call it (when your file is run as a script).
3. You can use generators and built-in functions to great effect if you learn them.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution, to avoid using too many variables:

```
def getOddEven(fileName):
    odd = 0
    even = 0
    print ('The numbers are: ')
    with open(fileName, 'r') as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            print(line),
            try:
                number = int(line)
                if (number%2 == 0):
                    even+=number
                else:
                    odd+=number
            except:
                pass
    return odd,even

def main():
    odd, even = getOddEven('numbers.txt')
    print('\nTheir total is:',odd + even)
    print('Total of odd numbers is: ', odd)
    print('Total of even numbers is: ', even)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: "Avoid using too many variables"? That's an interesting optimization technique... also, your solution uses more "variables" than mine?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but you loop over everything twice. :)

Comment: My CPU has to do something! Might as well show off the power of generators.